# Jmeter: sending json object array into request parameter

Tags: jmeter

i am trying to send http request using jMeter. in request parameter i have to send an array of json objects.

here is the piece of request i have created:
{
    "parameter1": "value1",
    "parameter2": "value2",
    "event[event_location_suggestions_attributes]": [ 
    {
    "latitude" : 13, 
    "longitude" : 13, 
    "address" : "asdsds"
    }
    ]
}

but the third parameter is not being sent with the request. i may be mistaking in the format for the third parameter. please help with this.

Is it doable?

Comment: can you show how you configure your HTTP Request ? is it post or get or other HTTP method ?

Comment: it is a post request.. and into a http request method

Comment: Can you show your Http Request configuration please ?

Comment: Just curious about the third parameter. It's valid JSON, but can you try setting it to just event instead of the array index notation you have right now?

Comment: i have tried setting it to "event[event_location_suggestions_attributes]": { "latitude" : 13, "longitude" : 13, "address" : "asdsds" } which is a non array index notation